# How to pass parameters as header api step pentaho?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I am doing an ETL to connect to an API that uses Oauth 2.0 has an acces method.
I have one `generate rows step` that define:

1. oauth_consumer_key ='A'
2. oauth_nonce = Get from response
3. oauth_signature = Get from response
4. oauth_signature_method='HMAC-SHA1'
5. oauth_timestamp=Get from response
6. oauth_token=Get from response
7. oauth_version=1.0
8. oauth_consumer_secret='X'
9. oauth_token_secret=Get from response
10. base_url='www.test.com'
11. http_method='POST'

Then I have a `js script step` that uses A JavaScript implementation of the Secure Hash Algorithm, SHA-1.
After that I have `Rest client step` that get the header from the before statement.

Finally I have an text file output step to see what is happening.

I got an error related with authorization. So I decided to use Postman to discover what was happening, and I found the solution, when I apply the option "pass parameters" it works.

I do not know how to  enable this option with pentaho. Trying to achieve that I passed the parameters in the header statement but it doesn't work.

Does anybody knows how to achieve that?

Thanks.

Comment: Stupid question, but did you try passing those values in the "Headers" tab of the REST Client step?

Comment: @nsousa Interesting word, stupid. Moreover when you do not give an answer...

If you read again the post you will se that I wrote about your suggest, so stupid answer :)

Comment: I meant my question was stupid, as I assume you did try that before posting. I didn't mean your question was stupid.

Comment: @nsousa Ok, don't worry. It was a misunderstanding.